# How to get client IP in .net core 3.1 API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm desperately trying to get the client's IP in my .Net core web API.
I've search every where, every tutorial, tried everything with no success...

I'm running the API on IIS if that's matters.
Every way that I've tried retuned wrong IP address (constantly the some IP).

Anyone knows a solution for that??

Comment: If you had the client's IP Address, what would you do with it? You cannot generally initiate other connections, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor _h)
    {
        httpContextAccessor = _h;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var ip=httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

        return View();
    }
}
```

In starup.cs.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: In case of load balancer or proxy this could not work I think. It covers probably direct connection.

Comment: @Hostel,  you can save it in session or cookie when get it.

Comment: @Karney. Thanks for answering, unfortunately that either didn't worked.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the idea behind it its part of a verification process allowing authentications from an "IP white list" rejecting requests from unknown IPs

Comment: I came across few threads about this issue saying that it is no longer possible to get the client's IP in .Net core v2 and above. can't find any reasonable explanation why on earth would Microsoft block that. frustrating...

Comment: Can you accept getting the client ip via javascript?